# concatenate multiple case statements

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following `SELECT` statement that works GREAT in SQL Server 2008.  Now instead of returning up to 4 rows, I need the results concatenated to a single result/row.

As you can infer, this script checks a medication table, and if a medication matches, it will `CASE` to the condition as the result.

I have included a `DISTINCT` in the beginning and `IS NOT NULL` at the end to minimize a `NULL` result from each non-matching medication or in the case of multiple matching medications (ie Diabetes, Diabetes).

All rows contain `varchar` data.

I've tried `CONCAT()` and `COALESCE()` to the best of my ability and come up short each time.

The existing query that returns the correct results on multiple rows is:

```
Select DISTINCT a.conditions 
from
    (select 
         CASE 
            WHEN medication like 'caduet'
                THEN 'Hypertension and Cholesterol'
            WHEN medication like '%actoplus%'
                                OR medication like '%actos%'
                                OR medication like '%amaryl%'
                THEN 'Diabetes'
            WHEN medication like '%altocor%'
                                OR medication like '%altoprev%'
                                OR medication like '%zocor%'
                THEN 'Cholesterol'
            WHEN medication like '%-nitro%'
                                OR medication like '%accupril%'
                                OR medication like '%zosin%'
                THEN 'Hypertension'
            ELSE NULL
        END as Conditions
    from 
        prescriptions
    where 
        patientid = @contactid
        and status = 'Active') a
where 
    a.conditions is not null
```

Thanks!

Comment: so if a med has a name like `aspirin-actoplus-nitro`, you want to output `aspirin diabetes hypertension`?

Comment: No.  When there's a match, it outputs the Then clause.  The existing script outputs each to an individual row.  I need them merged.  The accepted answer works as a standalone resolution, however it works best to do them as 4 individual CASE() with each nested in a MAX() so that I can embed the query into a larger query that does other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate them together using `for xml path`.  The exact syntax is a bit more involved:

```
with t as (<your query here>)
select stuff((select ',' + conditions
              from t
              for xml path(''), TYPE
             ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'
                    ), 1, 1, '');
```

Comment: This works as a standalone query.  It breaks down when I try to add it as an element within a larger select statement (and incorporate that into a stored procedure).  I understand that the previous statement, because of the xlmnamespaces, must be terminated with a semicolon, however there are no previous statements.

Answer (score 0):

Could be using STUFF

```
(Select DISTINCT a.conditions  =  STUFF(
                         ( SELECT ',' + CASE 
                            WHEN medication like 'caduet'
                            THEN 'Hypertension and Cholesterol'
                            WHEN medication like '%actoplus%'
                                OR medication like '%actos%'
                                OR medication like '%amaryl%'
                            THEN 'Diabetes'
                            WHEN medication like '%altocor%'
                                OR medication like '%altoprev%'
                                OR medication like '%zocor%'
                            THEN 'Cholesterol'
                            WHEN medication like '%-nitro%'
                                OR medication like '%accupril%'
                                OR medication like '%zosin%'
                            THEN 'Hypertension'
                            ELSE NULL
                            END as Conditions
                        from prescriptions
                        where patientid = @contactid
                        and status = 'Active'
                        ) a
                        where a.conditions is not null)) as 'Conditions'
```